# windows server dns, disable root zone request

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

Good day.
I have a simple problem, but i can't solve it.
I have a DC with domain sub.domain.com. And i have a publick domain with a website domain.com, hosted to another server and another dns.
When i try to request a fb.com(how a example) from domain PC. It request a fb.com.sub.domain.com, and it get answer from my DC DNS, than PC request a root domain fb.com.domain.com(without "sub"), and no answer from server(cause no local records)
how i can forbid a request to domain.com, and resolve it to internet
p.s. sorry for my english

lookup log

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> nslookup -d2 fb.com
------------
SendRequest(), len 40
HEADER:
opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NOERROR
header flags: query, want recursion
questions = 1, answers = 0, authority records = 0, additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer (63 bytes):
HEADER:
opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NOERROR
header flags: response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
questions = 1, answers = 1, authority records = 0, additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
ANSWERS:
-> 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa
type = PTR, class = IN, dlen = 11
name = localhost
ttl = 3600 (1 hour)

------------
Server: localhost
Address: 127.0.0.1

------------
SendRequest(), len 41
HEADER:
opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NOERROR
header flags: query, want recursion
questions = 1, answers = 0, authority records = 0, additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
fb.com.sub.domain.com, type = A, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer (110 bytes):
HEADER:
opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NXDOMAIN
header flags: response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
questions = 1, answers = 0, authority records = 1, additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
fb.com.sub.domain.com, type = A, class = IN
AUTHORITY RECORDS:
-> sub.domain.com
type = SOA, class = IN, dlen = 41
ttl = 3600 (1 hour)
primary name server = dc2.sub.domain.com
responsible mail addr = hostmaster.sub.domain.com
serial = 57017
refresh = 900 (15 mins)
retry = 600 (10 mins)
expire = 3600 (1 hour)
default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

------------
------------
SendRequest(), len 41
HEADER:
opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NOERROR
header flags: query, want recursion
questions = 1, answers = 0, authority records = 0, additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
fb.com.sub.domain.com, type = AAAA, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer (110 bytes):
HEADER:
opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NXDOMAIN
header flags: response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
questions = 1, answers = 0, authority records = 1, additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
fb.com.sub.domain.com, type = AAAA, class = IN
AUTHORITY RECORDS:
-> sub.domain.com
type = SOA, class = IN, dlen = 41
ttl = 3600 (1 hour)
primary name server = dc2.sub.domain.com
responsible mail addr = hostmaster.sub.domain.com
serial = 57017
refresh = 900 (15 mins)
retry = 600 (10 mins)
expire = 3600 (1 hour)
default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

------------
------------
SendRequest(), len 37
HEADER:
opcode = QUERY, id = 4, rcode = NOERROR
header flags: query, want recursion
questions = 1, answers = 0, authority records = 0, additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
fb.com.domain.com, type = A, class = IN

------------
DNS request timed out.
timeout was 2 seconds.
timeout (2 secs)
SendRequest failed
------------
SendRequest(), len 37
HEADER:
opcode = QUERY, id = 5, rcode = NOERROR
header flags: query, want recursion
questions = 1, answers = 0, authority records = 0, additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
fb.com.domain.com, type = AAAA, class = IN

------------
DNS request timed out.
timeout was 2 seconds.
timeout (2 secs)
SendRequest failed
------------
SendRequest(), len 24
HEADER:
opcode = QUERY, id = 6, rcode = NOERROR
header flags: query, want recursion
questions = 1, answers = 0, authority records = 0, additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
fb.com, type = A, class = IN

------------
DNS request timed out.
timeout was 2 seconds.
timeout (2 secs)
SendRequest failed
------------
SendRequest(), len 24
HEADER:
opcode = QUERY, id = 7, rcode = NOERROR
header flags: query, want recursion
questions = 1, answers = 0, authority records = 0, additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
fb.com, type = AAAA, class = IN

------------
DNS request timed out.
timeout was 2 seconds.
timeout (2 secs)
SendRequest failed
*** Request to localhost timed-out
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you're asking but the behavior you describe is correct and expected. Your query for fb.com is not fully qualified because it lacks a trailing dot. Because of that nslookup will append the primary DNS suffix of the client to the query and iteratively devolve THE QUERY to the root domain.

What are you actually trying to accomplish? Do you want the query to only query the fb.com DNS servers? If so, then fully qualify the query with a trailing dot, as such:

```
nslookup -d2 fb.com.
```

Comment: Sorry,seems to be i did wrong conclusion. I have a forwarding problem by publick DNS.
When i use a root hints, first(uncached) reqest take ~ 10sec.
If i turned off ruthints, and maked forwarding by 8.8.8.8 (for example), i have problem with resolve(logs that i attaced)
8.8.8.8 is avileble
if i use nslookup fb.com 8.8.8.8 - all good.
i have no antivirus/firewall.
i tryed to switch off windows-firewall - no result..